# How to debug Freezing/WiFi Disconnects

Tags: bluetooth, freeze, error-handling

Possible duplicate from a newbie.

I am facing issues with my Ubuntu 22.0.4 Laptop. For some time now, my Laptop keeps randomly having problems. It keeps disconnecting the Wifi and Bluetooth, when I try to open the settings or open/close programs, it takes forever and restarting the NetworkManager is also not possible. When shutting it down, it takes forever and booting afterwards also take some time.

What are some logs that I could look into and what should I look out for since I never really had to look into such things?

Thanks!

Comment: Basic logs to check are the `dmesg` program, maybe with `dmesg | less` and the file `/var/log/syslog` possibly with some other files in /var/log. If you can try connecting to a different wifi access point, on different hardware, that might verify if it's a problem with just one AP or all wifi, but since bluetooth is affected too I'm guessing it's a driver/HW issue